GetSystemMenu does not automatically gray out items
I am writing a fully self-drawn win32 window and try to implement the default title bar context menu by using GetSystemMenu() and then show it in WM_NCRBUTTONUP message. The doc clearly states that the items should be automatically grayed-out depend on the window state, but it does not seems like so.

The code I am using (just skip to the WM_NCRBUTTONUP section):
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <vssym32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")

#include <stdbool.h>


// These are defined in <windowsx.h> but we don't want to pull in whole header
// And we need them because coordinates are signed when you have multi-monitor setup.
#ifndef GET_X_PARAM
#define GET_X_PARAM(lp) ((int)(short)LOWORD(lp))
#endif

#ifndef GET_Y_PARAM
#define GET_Y_PARAM(lp) ((int)(short)HIWORD(lp))
#endif

static LRESULT
win32_custom_title_bar_example_window_callback(
    HWND handle,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM w_param,
    LPARAM l_param
); // Implementation is at the end of the file

int main() 
{
    // Support high-dpi screens
    if (!SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2)) {
        OutputDebugStringA("WARNING: could not set DPI awareness");
    }

    // Register a "Window Class"
    static const wchar_t* window_class_name = L"WIN32_CUSTOM_TITLEBAR_EXAMPLE";
    WNDCLASSEXW window_class = { 0 };
    {
        window_class.cbSize = sizeof(window_class);
        window_class.lpszClassName = window_class_name;
        // Set the procedure that will receive window messages (events)
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = win32_custom_title_bar_example_window_callback;
        // Ask to send WM_PAINT when resizing horizontally and vertically
        window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    }
    RegisterClassExW(&window_class);

    int window_style
        = WS_THICKFRAME   // required for a standard resizeable window
        | WS_SYSMENU      // Explicitly ask for the titlebar to support snapping via Win + ← / Win + →
        | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX  // Add maximize button to support maximizing via mouse dragging
        // to the top of the screen
        | WS_MINIMIZEBOX  // Add minimize button to support minimizing by clicking on the taskbar icon
        | WS_VISIBLE;     // Make window visible after it is created (not important)
    CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        window_class_name,
        L"Win32 Custom Title Bar Example",
        // The
        window_style,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    );

    // Run message loop
    for (MSG message = { 0 };;) {
        BOOL result = GetMessageW(&message, 0, 0, 0);
        if (result > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int
win32_dpi_scale(
    int value,
    UINT dpi
) {
    return (int)((float)value * dpi / 96);
}

// Adopted from:
// https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome/blob/master/source/gui/window_helper.hpp#L52-L64
static RECT
win32_titlebar_rect(
    HWND handle
) {
    SIZE title_bar_size = { 0 };
    const int top_and_bottom_borders = 2;
    HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(handle, L"WINDOW");
    UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(handle);
    GetThemePartSize(theme, NULL, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, NULL, TS_TRUE, &title_bar_size);
    CloseThemeData(theme);

    int height = win32_dpi_scale(title_bar_size.cy, dpi) + top_and_bottom_borders;

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(handle, &rect);
    rect.bottom = rect.top + height;
    return rect;
}

// Set this to 0 to remove the fake shadow painting
#define WIN32_FAKE_SHADOW_HEIGHT 1
// The offset of the 2 rectangles of the maximized window button
#define WIN32_MAXIMIZED_RECTANGLE_OFFSET 2

static RECT
win32_fake_shadow_rect(
    HWND handle
) {
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(handle, &rect);
    rect.bottom = rect.top + WIN32_FAKE_SHADOW_HEIGHT;
    return rect;
}

typedef struct {
    RECT close;
    RECT maximize;
    RECT minimize;
} CustomTitleBarButtonRects;

typedef enum {
    CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_None,
    CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Minimize,
    CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Maximize,
    CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Close,
} CustomTitleBarHoveredButton;

static CustomTitleBarButtonRects
win32_get_title_bar_button_rects(
    HWND handle,
    const RECT* title_bar_rect
) {
    UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(handle);
    CustomTitleBarButtonRects button_rects;
    // Sadly SM_CXSIZE does not result in the right size buttons for Win10
    int button_width = win32_dpi_scale(47, dpi);
    button_rects.close = *title_bar_rect;
    button_rects.close.top += WIN32_FAKE_SHADOW_HEIGHT;

    button_rects.close.left = button_rects.close.right - button_width;
    button_rects.maximize = button_rects.close;
    button_rects.maximize.left -= button_width;
    button_rects.maximize.right -= button_width;
    button_rects.minimize = button_rects.maximize;
    button_rects.minimize.left -= button_width;
    button_rects.minimize.right -= button_width;
    return button_rects;
}

static bool
win32_window_is_maximized(
    HWND handle
) {
    WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = { 0 };
    placement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    if (GetWindowPlacement(handle, &placement)) {
        return placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
    }
    return false;
}

static void
win32_center_rect_in_rect(
    RECT* to_center,
    const RECT* outer_rect
) {
    int to_width = to_center->right - to_center->left;
    int to_height = to_center->bottom - to_center->top;
    int outer_width = outer_rect->right - outer_rect->left;
    int outer_height = outer_rect->bottom - outer_rect->top;

    int padding_x = (outer_width - to_width) / 2;
    int padding_y = (outer_height - to_height) / 2;

    to_center->left = outer_rect->left + padding_x;
    to_center->top = outer_rect->top + padding_y;
    to_center->right = to_center->left + to_width;
    to_center->bottom = to_center->top + to_height;
}

static LRESULT
win32_custom_title_bar_example_window_callback(
    HWND handle,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM w_param,
    LPARAM l_param
) {
    CustomTitleBarHoveredButton title_bar_hovered_button =
        (CustomTitleBarHoveredButton)GetWindowLongPtrW(handle, GWLP_USERDATA);

    switch (message) {
        // Handling this event allows us to extend client (paintable) area into the title bar region
        // The information is partially coming from:
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#extending-the-client-frame
        // Most important paragraph is:
        //   To remove the standard window frame, you must handle the WM_NCCALCSIZE message,
        //   specifically when its wParam value is TRUE and the return value is 0.
        //   By doing so, your application uses the entire window region as the client area,
        //   removing the standard frame.
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
        if (!w_param) return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
        UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(handle);

        int frame_x = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXFRAME, dpi);
        int frame_y = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYFRAME, dpi);
        int padding = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER, dpi);

        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* params = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*)l_param;
        RECT* requested_client_rect = params->rgrc;

        requested_client_rect->right -= frame_x + padding;
        requested_client_rect->left += frame_x + padding;
        requested_client_rect->bottom -= frame_y + padding;

        if (win32_window_is_maximized(handle)) {
            requested_client_rect->top += padding;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    case WM_CREATE: {
        RECT size_rect;
        GetWindowRect(handle, &size_rect);

        // Inform the application of the frame change to force redrawing with the new
        // client area that is extended into the title bar
        SetWindowPos(
            handle, NULL,
            size_rect.left, size_rect.top,
            size_rect.right - size_rect.left, size_rect.bottom - size_rect.top,
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE
        );
        break;
    }
    case WM_ACTIVATE: {
        RECT title_bar_rect = win32_titlebar_rect(handle);
        InvalidateRect(handle, &title_bar_rect, FALSE);
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
        // Let the default procedure handle resizing areas
        LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
        switch (hit) {
        case HTNOWHERE:
        case HTRIGHT:
        case HTLEFT:
        case HTTOPLEFT:
        case HTTOP:
        case HTTOPRIGHT:
        case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
        case HTBOTTOM:
        case HTBOTTOMLEFT: {
            return hit;
        }
        }
        // Check if hover button is on maximize to support SnapLayout on Windows 11
        if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Maximize) {
            return HTMAXBUTTON;
        }

        // Looks like adjustment happening in NCCALCSIZE is messing with the detection
        // of the top hit area so manually fixing that.
        UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(handle);
        int frame_y = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYFRAME, dpi);
        int padding = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER, dpi);
        POINT cursor_point = { 0 };
        cursor_point.x = GET_X_PARAM(l_param);
        cursor_point.y = GET_Y_PARAM(l_param);
        ScreenToClient(handle, &cursor_point);
        if (cursor_point.y > 0 && cursor_point.y < frame_y + padding) {
            return HTTOP;
        }

        // Since we are drawing our own caption, this needs to be a custom test
        if (cursor_point.y < win32_titlebar_rect(handle).bottom) {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }

        return HTCLIENT;
    }
    case WM_PAINT: {
        bool has_focus = !!GetFocus();

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(handle, &ps);

        // Paint Background
        COLORREF bg_color = RGB(200, 250, 230);
        HBRUSH bg_brush = CreateSolidBrush(bg_color);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, bg_brush);
        DeleteObject(bg_brush);

        // Paint Title Bar
        HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(handle, L"WINDOW");

        COLORREF title_bar_color = RGB(150, 200, 180);
        HBRUSH title_bar_brush = CreateSolidBrush(title_bar_color);
        COLORREF title_bar_hover_color = RGB(130, 180, 160);
        HBRUSH title_bar_hover_brush = CreateSolidBrush(title_bar_hover_color);

        RECT title_bar_rect = win32_titlebar_rect(handle);

        // Title Bar Background
        FillRect(hdc, &title_bar_rect, title_bar_brush);

        COLORREF title_bar_item_color = has_focus ? RGB(33, 33, 33) : RGB(127, 127, 127);

        HBRUSH button_icon_brush = CreateSolidBrush(title_bar_item_color);
        HPEN button_icon_pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, title_bar_item_color);

        CustomTitleBarButtonRects button_rects =
            win32_get_title_bar_button_rects(handle, &title_bar_rect);

        UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(handle);
        int icon_dimension = win32_dpi_scale(10, dpi);

        { // Minimize button
            if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Minimize) {
                FillRect(hdc, &button_rects.minimize, title_bar_hover_brush);
            }
            RECT icon_rect = { 0 };
            icon_rect.right = icon_dimension;
            icon_rect.bottom = 1;
            win32_center_rect_in_rect(&icon_rect, &button_rects.minimize);
            FillRect(hdc, &icon_rect, button_icon_brush);
        }

        { // Maximize button
            bool const is_hovered = title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Maximize;
            if (is_hovered) {
                FillRect(hdc, &button_rects.maximize, title_bar_hover_brush);
            }
            RECT icon_rect = { 0 };
            icon_rect.right = icon_dimension;
            icon_rect.bottom = icon_dimension;
            win32_center_rect_in_rect(&icon_rect, &button_rects.maximize);
            SelectObject(hdc, button_icon_pen);
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH));
            if (win32_window_is_maximized(handle)) {
                // Draw the maximized icon
                Rectangle(hdc,
                    icon_rect.left + WIN32_MAXIMIZED_RECTANGLE_OFFSET,
                    icon_rect.top - WIN32_MAXIMIZED_RECTANGLE_OFFSET,
                    icon_rect.right + WIN32_MAXIMIZED_RECTANGLE_OFFSET,
                    icon_rect.bottom - WIN32_MAXIMIZED_RECTANGLE_OFFSET
                );
                FillRect(hdc, &icon_rect, is_hovered ? title_bar_hover_brush : title_bar_brush);
            }
            Rectangle(hdc, icon_rect.left, icon_rect.top, icon_rect.right, icon_rect.bottom);
        }

        { // Close button
            HPEN custom_pen = 0;
            if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Close) {
                HBRUSH fill_brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0xCC, 0, 0));
                FillRect(hdc, &button_rects.close, fill_brush);
                DeleteObject(fill_brush);
                custom_pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
                SelectObject(hdc, custom_pen);
            }
            RECT icon_rect = { 0 };
            icon_rect.right = icon_dimension;
            icon_rect.bottom = icon_dimension;
            win32_center_rect_in_rect(&icon_rect, &button_rects.close);
            MoveToEx(hdc, icon_rect.left, icon_rect.top, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, icon_rect.right + 1, icon_rect.bottom + 1);
            MoveToEx(hdc, icon_rect.left, icon_rect.bottom, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, icon_rect.right + 1, icon_rect.top - 1);
            if (custom_pen) DeleteObject(custom_pen);
        }
        DeleteObject(title_bar_hover_brush);
        DeleteObject(button_icon_brush);
        DeleteObject(button_icon_pen);
        DeleteObject(title_bar_brush);

        // Draw window title
        LOGFONT logical_font;
        HFONT old_font = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(SystemParametersInfoForDpi(SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT, sizeof(logical_font), &logical_font, false, dpi))) {
            HFONT theme_font = CreateFontIndirect(&logical_font);
            old_font = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, theme_font);
        }

        wchar_t title_text_buffer[255] = { 0 };
        int buffer_length = sizeof(title_text_buffer) / sizeof(title_text_buffer[0]);
        GetWindowTextW(handle, title_text_buffer, buffer_length);
        RECT title_bar_text_rect = title_bar_rect;
        // Add padding on the left
        int text_padding = 10; // There seems to be no good way to get this offset
        title_bar_text_rect.left += text_padding;
        // Add padding on the right for the buttons
        title_bar_text_rect.right = button_rects.minimize.left - text_padding;
        DTTOPTS draw_theme_options = { sizeof(draw_theme_options) };
        draw_theme_options.dwFlags = DTT_TEXTCOLOR;
        draw_theme_options.crText = title_bar_item_color;
        DrawThemeTextEx(
            theme,
            hdc,
            0, 0,
            title_text_buffer,
            -1,
            DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS,
            &title_bar_text_rect,
            &draw_theme_options
        );
        if (old_font) SelectObject(hdc, old_font);
        CloseThemeData(theme);

        // Paint fake top shadow. Original is missing because of the client rect extension.
        // You might need to tweak the colors here based on the color scheme of your app
        // or just remove it if you decide it is not worth it.
        static const COLORREF shadow_color = RGB(100, 100, 100);
        COLORREF fake_top_shadow_color = has_focus ? shadow_color : RGB(
            (GetRValue(title_bar_color) + GetRValue(shadow_color)) / 2,
            (GetGValue(title_bar_color) + GetGValue(shadow_color)) / 2,
            (GetBValue(title_bar_color) + GetBValue(shadow_color)) / 2
        );
        HBRUSH fake_top_shadow_brush = CreateSolidBrush(fake_top_shadow_color);
        RECT fake_top_shadow_rect = win32_fake_shadow_rect(handle);
        FillRect(hdc, &fake_top_shadow_rect, fake_top_shadow_brush);
        DeleteObject(fake_top_shadow_brush);

        EndPaint(handle, &ps);
        break;
    }
                 // Track when mouse hovers each of the title bar buttons to draw the highlight correctly
    case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE: {
        POINT cursor_point;
        GetCursorPos(&cursor_point);
        ScreenToClient(handle, &cursor_point);

        RECT title_bar_rect = win32_titlebar_rect(handle);
        CustomTitleBarButtonRects button_rects = win32_get_title_bar_button_rects(handle, &title_bar_rect);

        CustomTitleBarHoveredButton new_hovered_button = CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_None;
        if (PtInRect(&button_rects.close, cursor_point)) {
            new_hovered_button = CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Close;
        }
        else if (PtInRect(&button_rects.minimize, cursor_point)) {
            new_hovered_button = CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Minimize;
        }
        else if (PtInRect(&button_rects.maximize, cursor_point)) {
            new_hovered_button = CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Maximize;
        }
        if (new_hovered_button != title_bar_hovered_button) {
            // You could do tighter invalidation here but probably doesn't matter
            InvalidateRect(handle, &button_rects.close, FALSE);
            InvalidateRect(handle, &button_rects.minimize, FALSE);
            InvalidateRect(handle, &button_rects.maximize, FALSE);

            SetWindowLongPtrW(handle, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)new_hovered_button);
        }
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
                       // If the mouse gets into the client area then no title bar buttons are hovered
                       // so need to reset the hover state
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
        if (title_bar_hovered_button) {
            RECT title_bar_rect = win32_titlebar_rect(handle);
            // You could do tighter invalidation here but probably doesn't matter
            InvalidateRect(handle, &title_bar_rect, FALSE);
            SetWindowLongPtrW(handle, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_None);
        }
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
                     // Handle mouse down and mouse up in the caption area to handle clicks on the buttons
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN: {
        // Clicks on buttons will be handled in WM_NCLBUTTONUP, but we still need
        // to remove default handling of the click to avoid it counting as drag.
        //
        // Ideally you also want to check that the mouse hasn't moved out or too much
        // between DOWN and UP messages.
        if (title_bar_hovered_button) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Default handling allows for dragging and double click to maximize
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
                         // Map button clicks to the right messages for the window
    case WM_NCLBUTTONUP: {
        if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Close) {
            PostMessageW(handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Minimize) {
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (title_bar_hovered_button == CustomTitleBarHoveredButton_Maximize) {
            int mode = win32_window_is_maximized(handle) ? SW_NORMAL : SW_MAXIMIZE;
            ShowWindow(handle, mode);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
    case WM_NCRBUTTONUP: {
        if (w_param == HTCAPTION) {
            HMENU const sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, true);
            BOOL const result = TrackPopupMenu(sysMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD, GET_X_PARAM(l_param), GET_Y_PARAM(l_param), 0, handle, nullptr);
            if (result != 0) {
                PostMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, result, 0);
            }
        }
        return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
    }
    case WM_SETCURSOR: {
        // Show an arrow instead of the busy cursor
        SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
}


You could try to use EnableMenuItem function to gray the specified menu item.

I bet the system updates the system menu before displaying it under normal conditions, but since you are displaying the menu manually then the system doesn't get the chance to do that, so you will have to update it manually.
